# Chrome Error when running command yarn start

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am not aware of the technology used in this git repo but just trying to follow steps that are given by creator on https://github.com/paulmaunders/delivery-slot-bot

I have a windows machine and installed VMware player then Kali on it. Downloaded the repo and installed NPM in kali. When i run the command "Yarn Start" it is giving me the below error. I downloaded chrome and installed too but no joy. Any advice how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.
I have used Kali a bit so have some knowledge of Linux but cant figure this one out.

Thanks in advance

---

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/delivery-slot-bot-master/delivery-slot-bot$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ node ./src/index.js
index.js

Runs one-off

Options:
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]

Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[0421/142758.038038:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
#0 0x564e68efe879 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x564e68e5bc63 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x564e68e70013 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x564e6a60a95e service_manager::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#4 0x564e68a9fadc content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#5 0x564e68aeb72c service_manager::Main()
#6 0x564e68a9e0b1 content::ContentMain()
#7 0x564e68aea99d headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#8 0x564e68aea70b headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#9 0x564e6687b1b8 ChromeMain
#10 0x7f92b55efbbb __libc_start_main
#11 0x564e6687b02a _start

Received signal 6
#0 0x564e68efe879 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x564e68e5bc63 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x564e68efe401 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#3 0x7f92b7a76520 <unknown>
#4 0x7f92b5603081 gsignal
#5 0x7f92b55ee535 abort
#6 0x564e68efd265 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
#7 0x564e68e70461 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#8 0x564e6a60a95e service_manager::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#9 0x564e68a9fadc content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#10 0x564e68aeb72c service_manager::Main()
#11 0x564e68a9e0b1 content::ContentMain()
#12 0x564e68aea99d headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#13 0x564e68aea70b headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#14 0x564e6687b1b8 ChromeMain
#15 0x7f92b55efbbb __libc_start_main
#16 0x564e6687b02a _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffde55c0d60 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00007ffde55c2028 r13: 00007ffde55c1008 r14: 00007ffde55c1008 r15: 00007ffde55c1020
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffde55c0d60  bp: 00007ffde55c0fb0  bx: 00007f92b5783840
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f92b5603081  sp: 00007ffde55c0d60
  ip: 00007f92b5603081 efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/kali/Downloads/delivery-slot-bot-master/delivery-slot-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/home/kali/Downloads/delivery-slot-bot-master/delivery-slot-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:337:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:397:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:173:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentat
```

### ion about this command.

Comment: Why are you doing web dev on kali? It's not the best distro you know :p

Answer (score 0):

The thing with kali is that everytime you're logged in as the root user and everything you execute will run as root as well. But chrome knows that it's not a good idea to run it as root so it says no to you.

As the error message says, you can add the `--no-sandbox` to the launch option and make it run as root. However, this is not a very good idea. Running non-system applications or processes, including the ones with graphics, is not a good idea in general.

It's better that you switch to a non-root account and do all your web devs there, or just switch to a normal distro like Ubuntu.

Comment: No. That's not how you do it. `--no-sandbox` is the launch parameters for chrome. Not yarn. Just curious, why do you want to use kali for web dev. It's a distro I work with a lot. But I am in info. sec.

Comment: I am in info sec as well so prefer Kali, but not much experienced in it. So where do i add the --no-sandbox parameter ? I have found a script that checks slots for Tesco and ASDA, trying to get it to work

Comment: if you are in infosec you should really know better than to run some random code as a root user, which the app doesn't even require root permissions